# Why Are Colors Becoming Dim in my Browser Version of R Shiny Apps?

Tags: r, shiny, rstudio

As a reproducible example, we can use the `ui.R` and `server.R` files from:

https://github.com/bcaffo/courses/tree/master/09_DevelopingDataProducts/shiny/inputApp

When I run `runApp()` in RStudio the internal RStudio viewer displays an interface like this:

[image: good]

which is good, but when I click "Open in Browser" the Chrome and Firefox versions looks like this:

[image: dim]

What gives?

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.1.2 (2014-10-31)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252 
[2] LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets 
[6] methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] shiny_0.10.2.1

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] digest_0.6.4    htmltools_0.2.6 httpuv_1.3.2   
[4] mime_0.2        R6_2.0.1        Rcpp_0.11.3    
[7] RJSONIO_1.3-0   tools_3.1.2     xtable_1.7-4
```

Comment: You've exceeded your quota for shiny? ;)

Comment: @AndrewBarber hehe, yea probably not -- I am just running this locally not on shinyapps.io or anything

Comment: It means that the server did not respond. This happened sometimes in earlier versions of shiny, but has become a rare event nowadays. The code works for me (Windows 7 64 bit), so it seems to be operating system/version dependent. You should update shiny and post sessionInfo() for better diagnosis.

Comment: @DieterMenne OK, I will post sessionInfo(), good idea. But the server still works fine --  I can interact with it and everything. The colors are just weird. I'm on Win 8.1 with R 3.1.2 I believe.

Comment: Ok, that's an interesting new twitch....